# When do clock hands meet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity

Let there be a clock with two hands, one for measuring hours and one for measuring minutes both pointing upwards. They have constant angular velocities

$T_h=12 hours=12* 60 minutes = 12*60*60s=12*3600 s=43200s$

and

$T_m=60minutes=60*60s=3600s$

where $T_h$ is the hour's hand period and $T_m$ is the minute's hand period

by definition $Tω=2π \Rightarrow ω= \frac{2π}{T}$ where $ω$ is the angular velocity

so

$ω_h= \frac{2π}{T_h}=\frac{2π}{43200}=\frac{π}{21600} \frac{rad}{s}$

and

$ω_m=\frac{2π}{T_m}=\frac{2π}{3600}=\frac{π}{1800}\frac{rad}{s}$

where $ω_h$ is the constant angular velocity of the hour hand and $ω_m$ is the constant angular velocity of the minute hand

$ω = \frac{dθ}{dt} \Rightarrow ωdt=dθ \Rightarrow \int_0^tωdt=\int_0^θdθ \Rightarrow [ωt]_0^t = [θ]_0^θ \Rightarrow θ = ωt$

but I dont know what to do from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've solved for $\theta(t)$ for both hands. Now divide both angles by $2\pi$ and find the remainder. Find all the times when the remainders are equal.

$\theta_h=\frac{\pi}{21600}\frac{rad}{s}t $

$\theta_m=\frac{\pi}{1800}\frac{rad}{s}t $

Define revolutions $R = \frac{\theta}{2 \pi}$

$R_h=\frac{1}{43200}\frac{1}{s}t $

$R_m=\frac{1}{3600}\frac{1}{s}t $

Now round down both $R_h$ and $R_m$ and compare the decimal. You are looking for values of $t$ that satisfy $R_h-H=R_m-M$ where $H$ and $M$ are integers found by rounding $R_h$ and $R_m$ down.

Graphically, look for wherever the two lines cross in this figure:

[image]

Comment: the graph would be more readable if you could delete the vertical lines that occur when the minute hand drops from 1.0 rev to 0 rev.